# How AnyDesk file Transfering is like jet?

Tags: windows, internet, bluetooth, anydesk

Well guys in the past I used my flash to Transfer heavy files to another pc

but now ...

I get a remote control on that pc with anydesk software

and its really simple and fast

my question is that how this is happening . my Internet upload speed is really slow and weak and if I want upload 500 mg file in the Internet it takes nearlly 30 min .

but when I want to send this file to my another pc with anydesk software it takes less than 2 min

How anydesk transfer my files by this speed? ( I dont have any bluetooth )

It seems that by this way no one need a flash anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to send this file to my another pc with anydesk software it
> takes less than 2 min

You say "my other PC".  This is a Local Network setup and that is why it can be so fast. The transfer is not going out to the internet.

You can get the same speed just by mapping folders locally. That will be fast as well.

Internet is not involved here.

> It seems that by this way no one need a flash anymore

It depends. I do not use USB keys on my internal network as there is no need. Sometimes for different (and remote) networks and computers I may still use USB keys.

Comment: So If I want to send some files to one of my friends which have 1 km distance to me is this still local network?

Comment: If you need remote access:  USB Key is still good; the speed of your internet will come into play; and you would need secure access. It is more complicated remotely but can be made to work.